# Linking file list and retrieving an input in Java

Tags: java, file, arraylist, io

I'm currently programming a search engine in Java using Wolfam App, I have the app as an object in another class. I created two file lists, one for the questions that the user already typed and one for the answers that the app generated. When I created a try loop to show on the console if the question was asked or not.
My question is if the the question was already asked how can use the answer list file to retrieve the answer for that question instead of using the app and downloading the answer ?
I tried everything I think a multi list array would do it but my memory is a bit grey with that topic, I tried creating a method that can be used in the try loop with the get(i); but I don't know how to link the right answer with the question.
My code is:

```
public class Assignment  {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws  IOException, FileNotFoundException {

        String s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("please type in your question");

        File q = new File("Questions.List");
        File a = new File("Answers.List");
        FileWriter w = new FileWriter(q, true);
        PrintWriter  p = new PrintWriter(w);
        p.println(s1);
        p.close();

        // Create an instance of the Wolfram Alpha API - including your AppID key       
        WolframAlpha WOLFRAM_ALPHA = new WolframAlpha("apple_id");

        // Sample question - capturing the response from Wolfram Alpha in a String called response, and printing to console
        String response = WOLFRAM_ALPHA.query(s1);
        Scanner Ans = new Scanner (a);

        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(q);

            int lineNum = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                lineNum++;
                if(line.contains(s1))  
                    System.out.println( "This is question number" + lineNum + " " + "And has been asked previously ");
                if (!q.equals(s1))                  
                    break;          
            }
            String [] v =response.split("<section><title>");

            for(int i = 0; i<v.length; i++) {
                if(v[i].contains("Result"))
                    System.out.println("Response: " + i + v[i]);
                else if (v[i].contains("formula"))
                    System.out.println("Response: " + i + v[i]);
                else if (v[i].contains("Response"))
                    System.out.println("Response: " + i + v[i]);
                else if (v[i].contains("Definition"))
                    System.out.println("Response: " + i + v[i]);

                FileWriter wr = new FileWriter(a, true);
                PrintWriter  pr = new PrintWriter(wr);
                pr.println(i + v[i]);
                pr.close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if you really want to disclose your Wolfram Alpha AppID key here ;-)